# NOT EXISTS em update?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte SQL:

```
insert into teste (id,nome)
select 2,'João' from dual 
where not exists(select * from teste where nome = 'João')
```

Queria fazer o mesmo com update? Tem alguma forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que não está muito claro na pergunta é que você quer evitar que uma atualização gere um nome duplicado na tabela, não é mesmo?

A forma mais correta de fazer isto é criar um índice único para o campo de forma que se houver qualquer tentative de inserir ou atualizar um nome para um valor que já existe o banco de dados vai lançar um erro que você então pode tratar da forma como bem entender.

Se você precisa mesmo de uma consulta, pode fazer um `update` com `join`, da seguinte forma:

```
update teste t1 
left outer join teste t2 
  on t2.nome = '<novo nome>'
  and t2.id != <id sendo atualizado>
set t1.nome = '<novo nome'>
where t1.id = <id sendo atualizado> and t2.id is null;
```

Basicamente o que é feito acima é o seguinte:

- Cruza a tabela com ela mesma, porém permitindo que a segunda tabela não contenha nenhum registro, o que vai sinalizar que não tem um nome duplicado
- Da segunda tabela, seleciona registros com o mesmo nome: `t2.nome = ''
- Exceto o que está sendo atualizado: `t2.id != <id sendo atualizado>`
- Finalmente `t2.id is null` verifica que no `join` não foi encontrado nenhum registro com o mesmo nome, portanto o `outer join` retorna campos com valores nulos.

Veja um exemplo completo:

```
create table teste (id int, nome varchar(100));

insert into teste (id, nome) values (1, 'Joao');
insert into teste (id, nome) values (2, 'Jose');
insert into teste (id, nome) values (3, 'Maria');

update teste t1 
left outer join teste t2 
  on t2.nome = 'Joao'
  and t2.id != 2
set t1.nome = 'Joao' 
where t1.id = 2 and t2.id is null;

update teste t1 
left outer join teste t2 
  on t2.nome = 'Joao2'
  and t2.id != 3
set t1.nome = 'Joao2' 
where t1.id = 3 and t2.id is null;
```

O primeiro `update` tenta atualizar `Jose` para o valor `Joao`, mas não faz nada porque já existe outro registro.

O segundo `update` tenta atualizar `Maria` para `Jose2`, o que funciona corretamente.

O resultado final é:

> 1 Joao
>
> 2 Jose
>
> 3 Joao2

#### [Veja o exemplo funcional no SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d833/1)

Answer (score 3):

Procurando na web eu achei o comando INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, ele tem a finalidade de inserir se o registro não existir e de atualizar se já existir, baseando-se na chave:

```
INSERT INTO teste (id, nome) VALUES(2, 'João') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id=2
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: Não quero que atualize, só que não faça o update caso existir algum registro igual ao nome = 'Joao', como acontece no caso do insert

Comment: Então bastaria você fazer igual o insert mesmo:
update teste set nome = 'João' where not exists(select * from teste where nome = 'João')

Comment: Você já testou executar no seu MySQL? Aqui dá erro de syntax...

Comment: Na realidade eu não tinha testado no mysql, no firebird ele funciona, mas pensando bem, por que você precisaria deste comando ? Qual sua necessidade?

Comment: Verificar pelo nome e telefone se usuario já está cadastrado, então precisaria verificar no update também certo?

Comment: como faço no insert...E não pretendia fazer um select antes, para fazer a verificação, entende?
Utilizo PHP.

Comment: Nesse caso não será possível, você realmente terá que antes fazer um select buscando o id por exemplo e se ele não for nulo (usando o usuaário e senha como filtro), ele não existiria no seu cadastro.